# Hibernate: Self-Referencing but with additonal information and both directions

Tags: hibernate

I have (if not correct I can change it - JSON below is fixed):

```
Entity: Node { Id, Name, List<Edge>, rowversion }
Entity: Edge { fromNode, fromNodeId, toNode, toNodeId, relationType }
```

where rowversion is for optimistic concurrency and Id is PK serial

Example JSON:

```json
{
   "graph":[
      {
         "node":"A",
         "relations":[
            {
               "node":"B",
               "type":"parent"
            },
            {
               "node":"C",
               "type":"parent"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "node":"B",
         "relations":[
            {
               "node":"A",
               "type":"child"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "node":"C",
         "relations":[
            {
               "node":"A",
               "type":"child"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Entities:

```
Node Id = 0, "A", rowversion = 0
Node Id = 1, "B", rowversion = 0
Node Id = 2, "C", rowversion = 0
Edge fromNode="A", fromNodeId=0, toNode="B", toNodeId=1, relationType="parent"
Edge fromNode="A", fromNodeId=0, toNode="C", toNodeId=2, relationType="parent"
Edge fromNode="B", fromNodeId=1, toNode="A", toNodeId=0, relationType="cild"
Edge fromNode="C", fromNodeId=2, toNode="A", toNodeId=0, relationType="cild"
```

Hibernate (Spring) and PostgreSQL is used.

With raw SQL I would write a CTE - but how can I do it with Hibernate so that is done in one statement so that rowversion is not increased?

A simple solution would be:

1. Insert Node and return Ids
2. Insert Edges (with setting fromNode and toNode ids manually)

But I want Hibernate to do that for me ;-)

Comment: Could you please formulate an actual question? You are writing about CTEs but then your "workaround" mentions inserts. Do you want to write this data or read it from the database? Also, how does your entity model look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS playground;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS playground.edges;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS playground.nodes;

CREATE TABLE playground.nodes
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    node_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE playground.edges
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    from_node_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES playground.nodes(id),
    to_node_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES playground.nodes(id),
    type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

And the java code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nodes", schema = "playground", catalog = "postgres")
public class NodesEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "node_name", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String nodeName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fromNode", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<EdgesEntity> edges = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getNodeName() { return nodeName; }
    public void setNodeName(String nodeName) { this.nodeName = nodeName; }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "edges", schema = "playground", catalog = "postgres")
public class EdgesEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "from_node_id", nullable = false)
    private NodesEntity fromNode;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "to_node_id", nullable = false)
    private NodesEntity toNode;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String type;

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public NodesEntity getFromNode() { return fromNode; }
    public void setFromNode(NodesEntity fromNode) { this.fromNode = fromNode; }

    public NodesEntity getToNode() { return toNode; }
    public void setToNode(NodesEntity toNode) { this.toNode = toNode; }

    public String getType() { return type; }
    public void setType(String type) { this.type = type; }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Session session = getSession();
    try {
        NodesEntity nodeA = new NodesEntity();
        nodeA.setNodeName("A");

        NodesEntity nodeB = new NodesEntity();
        nodeB.setNodeName("B");

        EdgesEntity entityAToB = new EdgesEntity();
        entityAToB.setFromNode(nodeA);
        entityAToB.setToNode(nodeB);
        entityAToB.setType("parent");

        nodeA.edges.add(entityAToB);

        EdgesEntity entityBToA = new EdgesEntity();
        entityBToA.setFromNode(nodeB);
        entityBToA.setToNode(nodeA);
        entityBToA.setType("child");

        nodeB.edges.add(entityBToA);

        session.save(nodeA);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

I was able to solve it. I was missing an annotation (CascadeType.ALL):

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "to_node_id", nullable = false)
private NodesEntity toNode;
```